# Are all virtual files in Linux device files?

Tags: linux, devices, proc

The following two files are virtual files:

```
/dev/sda1
/proc/cpuinfo
```

I know that `/dev/sda1` is a device file (that points to a device driver), so when I access this file, I am actually accessing the device driver.

But what about `/proc/cpuinfo`, is this file also a device file? If it is, are all other virtual files in Linux device files?

Answer (score 6):

All the files in `/proc` are provided by the `proc` file system, which is described thus in [its manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html):

> The `proc` filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem which provides an interface to kernel data structures.

This is a special file system provided by the kernel to provide access to the data it stores, *e.g.* about the CPU (`cpuinfo`), about processes (in the numeric directories in `/proc`, corresponding to each process identifier)... The files inside it aren’t device files, they are effectively endpoints for function calls into the kernel to retrieve information from it.

Other special file systems include `devtmpfs` and `sysfs`.

So no, all “virtual” files aren’t device files. Arguably, device files aren’t virtual at all, since device nodes exist as real files; the way they act is not the same as what most people think of as files, but they are files nevertheless.

These questions might help you understand all this better:

- [What happens when I run the command cat /proc/cpuinfo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121702/86440)
- [What is the difference between procfs and sysfs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4884/86440)
- [Why is proc called a file system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203948/86440)

Answer (score 3):

No.  `/proc` on Linux is a pseudo-filesystem  which provides an interface to kernel data structures.  There are no character or block special files in it in the same sense as the files under `/dev` (you can't use the `/proc` files for mounting a filesystem or talk to a modem or tape drive etc).

This filesystem is fully explained by the `proc(5)` manual on your system (`man 5 proc`).